# Simple Markov chain algorithm

Tags: r

The following code is a simple Markov chain algorithm written in R with the task to model the movement of rental cars between 2 towns since the customers have the privilege to return their car in whatever towns is convenient for them. These 2 towns have an initial number of rental cars and after a number of iterations I wanted to know what is the final availability of cars in each (town). It is being provided the transition matrix of probabilities (p1 & p2) and the full code. My problem is that I can't find the flaw in the code because R gives no result. I would appreciate any help.

```
p1 <- c(0.6,0.4)            # probabilities of Athens facilities (1st % means: stays) 
p2 <- c(0.7,0.3)            #probabilities of Chania facilities (1st % means: stays in town)
Athens.start <- 200     #number of cars in Athens at the start of the period
Chania.start <- 200     #number of cars in Chania at the start of the period
nsims <- 15
Athens <- rep(0,nsims+1)
Chania <- rep(0,nsims+1)

#Function for deciding whether to move or not a car from its initial facility
move <- function(p1,p2,Athens,Chania,i ) {
    repeat {
       #position1 is related with 1st location (Athens)
       position1 <- sample(x=c(1,2),size=1,prob=p1)
       if (position1==1) {
          Athens[i]=Athens[i]+1
          Chania[i]=Chania[i]-1
       } else {
          Athens[i]=Athens[i]-1
          Chania[i]=Chania[i]+1
       }
       #position2 is related with 2nd location (Chania)
       position2<-sample(x=c(1,2),size=1,prob=p2)
       if (position2==1) {
          Chania[i]=Chania[i]+1
          Athens[i]=Athens[i]-1
       } else {
          Chania[i]=Chania[i]-1
          Athens[i]=Athens[i]+1}
       }
       return(Athens[i])
       return(Chania[i]) 
       break
     }
     #Basic Function for simulating the movement of cars between facilities 
     cars.sims<-function(Athens.start,Chania.start,nsim) {
        Athens<-vector(length=nsim+1)
        Chania<-vector(length=nsim+1)
        Athens[1]<-Athens.start
        Chania[1]<-Chania.start
        for (i in 1:nsim) {
           Athens[i+1]<-move(p1,p2,Athens,Chania)
           Chania[i+1]<-move(p1,p2,Athens,Chania)
         }
        Towns<-rbind(Athens,Chania)
        return(Towns)
      }
```

Comment: as currently written, your brackets aren't currently nested properly ...

Comment: What is the point in having two `return` statements in a row? The second one wouldn't be reached. Also, you haven't terminated the definition of the first function before launching into the definition of the second. Pay attention to the level of indentation. The fact that your final `}` isn't flush against the left of the code is a visual indicator that something is wrong.

Comment: Also the two lines which assign `move(p1,p2,Athens,Chania)` to two different vectors don't make sense either. Your intention seems to be that the first assignment will get the value of the first return statement and the second assignment will get the value of the second return statement. That isn't how R works. Both assignments assign exactly the same value to each vector. You should modify your code so that `move` returns either a vector or list of length 2, and have the calling code assign the individual components to `Athens` and `Chania`.

Comment: Thanks Ben & John. The mistakes you mention are due to the fact I'm not a developer. I'try to fix the code.

Comment: for the brackets, it might help to use an integrated development environment (IDE) such as RStudio, which will help you indent your code blocks properly - makes it much easier to see such problems.